# Force graph labels overlay each other

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to move from visjs to d3js cause visjs always redraw the same data in a different way. The problem I faced is that d3js draw my nodes too close to each other, so labels overlay each others(see screenshot).

[image]

D3js is not an easy tool for beginners, but I'm sure there is some way to fix this problem. Please help to solve it.

```
const links = edges.map((edge) => ({source: edge.from, target: edge.to}));
        function getNodeColor(node) {
            return node.color.background;
        }

        const width = 1000;
        const height = 800;

        const svg = d3.select('svg');
        svg.selectAll('*').remove();
        svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

        // simulation setup with all forces
        const linkForce = d3
            .forceLink()
            .id(function (link) {
                return (link as NetworkNode).id;
            })
            .strength(function (link) {
                return 1;
            });

        const simulation = d3
            .forceSimulation()
            .force('link', linkForce)
            .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-120))
            .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

        const linkElements = svg
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'links')
            .selectAll('line')
            .data(links)
            .enter()
            .append('line')
            .attr('stroke-width', 1)
            .attr('stroke', 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2)');

        const nodeElements = svg
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'nodes')
            .selectAll('circle')
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('r', 10)
            .attr('fill', getNodeColor);

        const textElements = svg
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'texts')
            .selectAll('text')
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .text(function (node) {
                return node.label;
            })
            .attr('font-size', 15)
            .attr('dx', 15)
            .attr('dy', 4);

        simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', () => {
            nodeElements
                .attr('cx', function (node) {
                    return node.x;
                })
                .attr('cy', function (node) {
                    return node.y;
                });
            textElements
                .attr('x', function (node) {
                    return node.x;
                })
                .attr('y', function (node) {
                    return node.y;
                });
            linkElements
                .attr('x1', function (link) {
                    return (link as d3.SimulationLinkDatum<any>).source.x;
                })
                .attr('y1', function (link) {
                    return (link as d3.SimulationLinkDatum<any>).source.y;
                })
                .attr('x2', function (link) {
                    return (link as d3.SimulationLinkDatum<any>).target.x;
                })
                .attr('y2', function (link) {
                    return (link as d3.SimulationLinkDatum<any>).target.y;
                });
        });

        // @ts-ignore
        simulation.force('link').links(links);
```

Comment: Force graphs aren't adjustable in that sense because the position reflects the force vector. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455378/1264804 What were you hoping to see in a layout?

Comment: @isherwood something like https://ibb.co/P1Z3DD9 . The distance between each node is more than in d3js, as a result, all labels are more readable.